# Redmine is not working properly. How I can solve this issue?

Tags: nginx, passenger, redmine, freebsd

Please help me with Redmine. I had a working Redmine at FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p4 with Nginx and Passenger. But after some latest updates, my Redmine is not working properly.

I have an error in passenger.log:

> [ E 2018-10-09 16:10:01.0750 42785/Tb
>   age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for
>   application /usr/local/www/redmine: The application encountered the
>   following error: undefined method `active_record' for
>    (NoMethodError)   Error ID: 8412e2de   Error details saved to:
>   /tmp/passenger-error-wIhbfb.html

What can I do with these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the gems required, just go to where the redmine code is and type

```
bundle install
```

Restart nginx and see if keep saying the same error.

Comment: I tried it. But I see the same error. And I forgot to add that I see in the daily security run output email next strings:

`Checking for packages with mismatched checksums:`  

`rubygem-activeresource4-4.1.0: missing file /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4/doc/activeresource-4.1.0/rdoc/ActiveResource.html`
....[cut]....
rubygem-pkg-config-1.3.1: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4/specifications/pkg-config-1.3.1.gemspec
rubygem-rack-2.0.5,3: missing file /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4/doc/rack-2.0.5/rdoc/FCGI.html`

And other similiar strings.

Comment: Those appear to be documentation which won't break it, however the package might not have installed correctly.  You could try checking if there is a newer package available or updating your ports tree and installing from ports.